# Concatenate two columns of an array into a new one

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the array `range` with 3 columns and 10 rows.

How can I concatenate the contents of column 1 with column 2 and push them to a new range `dataEnome`?

I'm using the following loop, but it isn't very efficient:

```
var dataEnome =[];
for (i=0; i<range.length; i++){
  dataEnome.push(range[i][0])+(range[i][1]); 
};
```

The range looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of how range actually looks like?

Comment: I didn't use the actual data but have a look at my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data mapping you can consider using the `array.map` API.

**Example:**

```js
var range =
    [
        [ 'col1.a', 'col2.1', 'c' ],
        [ 'col1.b', 'col2.2', '3' ],
        [ 'col1.c', 'col2.3', '6' ],
        [ 'col1.d', 'col2.4', '9' ],
        [ 'col1-e', 'col2.5', '1c' ],
        [ 'col1-f', 'col2.6', '6c' ],
        [ 'col1-g', 'col2.7', '7c' ],
        [ 'col1-h', 'col2.8', '8c' ],
        [ 'col1-i', 'col2.9', '9c' ],
        [ 'col1-j', 'col2.10', '0c' ],
    ];
var dataEnome =range.map(row => { return row[0] + row[1]});
console.log(dataEnome);
```

For more example usages for `map`;

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate each record from both column

You may do something like this:

```js
var dataEnome =[];
  for (i=0; i<range.getValues().length; i++){
    dataEnome.push(range.getValues()[i][0]+range.getValues()[i][1]);
  };
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

... besides `dataEnome.push(range[i][0])+(range[i][1]);` does most probably feature a broken syntax ...
shouldn't it be `dataEnome.push(range[i][0] + range[i][1]);` or `dataEnome.push(range[i][0].concat(range[i][1]));`
... I do not consider the OP's solution to be not that efficient.

One only could transform it into a reusable and more functional style ...

```js
function collectConcatenatedFirstTwoRowColumns(collector, row) {

    collector.push(row[0].concat(" / ", row[1]));
    return collector;
}

var
    range = [
        ["0, 0", "0, 1", "0, 2"],
        ["1, 0", "1, 1", "1, 2"],
        ["2, 0", "2, 1", "2, 2"],
        ["3, 0", "3, 1", "3, 2"],
        ["4, 0", "4, 1", "4, 2"],
        ["5, 0", "5, 1", "5, 2"]
    ],
    dataEnome = range.reduce(collectConcatenatedFirstTwoRowColumns, []);

console.log(dataEnome);
```